# Download video from a direct URL with Python

Tags: python, video

I want to download videos with python. I tried using youtube-dl, but the site I wish to download videos from is not supported. How to download videos in Python. First I tried to get the direct link of the video I want to download from keepvid.com after following this link http://www.kmcgraphics.com/bits-of-code/how-to-get-the-direct-url-path-to-flv-video-files-on-youtube-for-free/. I got the following link http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/108994262975881368074/Po270 When I tried to run the following piece of code I am getting errors.

```
import urllib
test=urllib.URLopener()
test.retrieve("http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/108994262975881368074/Po270.flv","testout.flv")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "downl.py", line 14, in <module>
test.retrieve("http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/108994262975881368074/Po270.flv","testout.flv")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 359, in open_http
return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 376, in http_error
return self.http_error_default(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 381, in http_error_default
raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)
IOError: ('http error', 301, 'Moved Permanently', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7f094d5d5290>)
```

I am new to Python. So please help me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`urllib.URLopener` doesn't handle redirects by default

Use [urllib.FancyURLopener](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.FancyURLopener) instead:

```
import urllib
test=urllib.FancyURLopener()
test.retrieve("http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/108994262975881368074/Po270.flv","testout.flv")
```