# How can I use Python to download a video from a website?

Tags: javascript, python, video

There's a really cool course on [Kadenze](https://www.kadenze.com) on machine learning.

Much like [coursera-dl](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl) does, I would like to download all of the course videos so I can reference them later.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume I've logged in and have access to the [page with the videos](https://www.kadenze.com/courses/creative-applications-of-deep-learning-with-tensorflow-i/sessions/introduction-to-tensorflow) on it.

How can I download the video(s) on the page with Python?

Extra info (will be edited as more information is found):

- There doesn't seem to be a specific URL for each video that I can
  access. (Pressing "Copy this link" on the buttons that go to the next
  videos results in `javascript:void(0);` on the clipboard.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: @Jameson The thing is, the videos don't have a specific URL that I can find, otherwise I would do that in a heartbeat. (See "Extra Info"). Thanks though.

Comment: maybe use some browser extension to download all videos on page. It needs less work.

Comment: Check this answer: [Answer by Ngenator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744146/5307040)

Comment: @furas Surprisingly, that worked. Thank you! Apparently I don't need to write a program for it after all. Right now I'm using "Video Downloader Professional" on Chrome. It doesn't seem to see all the videos yet, but I'm sure that's just troubleshooting.

Comment: @rakshith1124 thanks for the alternative, but I still cant find any link to the videos themselves... If there was a link just to the video I would totally use that.

Comment: Troubleshooting done: I just needed to click on each video in the session in order for it to pop up in the extension window. Then, you can download them all, and it even get's the order (mostly) right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2019 Update

I know very late to this game, but [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) seems ideal for this purpose.
The name is a misnomer they cover many more video hosting sites (other than youtube), and works very well.

Comment: For now, this is a link-only answer, which is discouraged on stack overflow - this may be better as a comment unless you’re willing to explain how it works (the relevant code seems to be in `downloader/http.py`). That said, this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for and I did not know it existed, so thank you!