# is there a way to download an embedded video as an mp4 file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, embedded-video

I have made some code that gets embedded videos from a website selenium and I can't seem to find a way to download the video as an mp4 file.

my current goal is to be able to get embedded video links and download them as mp4 files

is there a way to get/download the videos from the embedded links?

here is a sample video link

https://disk29.cizgifilmlerizle.com/getvid?evid=wXxbWGkc-3ZZCUx6abGKPTcpL6i8XBzhDB8XKviBEOHN0gzJ1I-2z4GvZkwOH2Vl1bNzGTCv7odEnDE4TqxnlxQLG1MptkGgGR8Inf39W-Pvr-j6t_cQYYtavMV5FXxfrQmObKWMniKVA14I0Z8cpq9-DAtxeq8yGGVUOpKh74OdwA5ceKOPH_EultcyI3GPijjPxqhALm-TcinRBn8qm8vnTc_hSMS3FksWqNk4BsZEufF1uRaB4G3LLBB3dIy6hYjqpcEmb2VGvQHgXwmDgR29kZ29rB4Z5vb_AnoAfFYx504-GubrylwDRS9yU4tZiwcmvTAhO_VTycIrLNaD2EqJ9SKkP5e7MSv84qQDEMv45EVrlacrPNUjEJ4uWEei1GV1wdGpB0TbTEBRRVUnTdwhwCklMpntnTOkmXBrLY69FlFqwEn5PHnOGTpde5yW1abYBvX6qCJ-1LLKWKhz4w

if the link doesn't work here is the html from the link

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="https://disk29.cizgifilmlerizle.com/getvid?evid=wXxbWGkc-3ZZCUx6abGKPTcpL6i8XBzhDB8XKviBEOHN0gzJ1I-2z4GvZkwOH2Vl1bNzGTCv7odEnDE4TqxnlxQLG1MptkGgGR8Inf39W-Pvr-j6t_cQYYtavMV5FXxfrQmObKWMniKVA14I0Z8cpq9-DAtxeq8yGGVUOpKh74OdwA5ceKOPH_EultcyI3GPijjPxqhALm-TcinRBn8qm8vnTc_hSMS3FksWqNk4BsZEufF1uRaB4G3LLBB3dIy6hYjqpcEmb2VGvQHgXwmDgR29kZ29rB4Z5vb_AnoAfFYx504-GubrylwDRS9yU4tZiwcmvTAhO_VTycIrLNaD2EqJ9SKkP5e7MSv84qQDEMv45EVrlacrPNUjEJ4uWEei1GV1wdGpB0TbTEBRRVUnTdwhwCklMpntnTOkmXBrLY69FlFqwEn5PHnOGTpde5yW1abYBvX6qCJ-1LLKWKhz4w" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Most video links have a file extension but the links I get don't have extensions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download video from a direct URL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743968/download-video-from-a-direct-url-with-python)

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work because the link in the src has no extension.